# JS not detecting a function?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

So i have this in index.php:

```
        <script type='text/javascript' src='images/submit.js'></script>
```

inside that file i have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function sendEmail() {
            console.log("function send email run");
                var url = "sendemail.php";

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       //alert(data);
                       document.getElementById("resultmsg").innerHTML = data;//$("#resultmsg").html(data);
                   }
                 });

            return false;
            }
});
```

and I am trying to call it from(also index.php):

```
<form name="emailform" action="" onsubmit="return sendEmail();" method="post">
```

but i get this error:

```
TypeError: sendEmail is not a function
```

Comment: You've a [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope) problem.

Comment: move the function out of the document ready and declare it before the form.  If you are using jquery, why not just give your form an id and use `$('#form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDeault(); \\ ajax stuff });`

Comment: Also, make sure your script is really loaded. Open Net(work) tab on the Dev Tools of your browser, and check if your script is in the list of loaded resources.

Comment: Even if i put
 $('#emailform').submit( function(e) { 
     e.preventDeault(); 
     alert('test');
  });
in the index.php in the head inside <script> tags it still fails, and submits the form normally :(
edit. cant figure out how to do a code tag sorry

Comment: The code in your comment above belongs in `.ready(function () {...})`. If you're using an inline handler, then you need a global handler function, i.e. declare it directly in script "root". Please read the article I've linked above. Did you check the script really is loaded?

Comment: @RadekWysocki, that's because your form has a `name` of emailform - not an **id**

Comment: I am so lost now... My script does work but cannot be triggered by the onclick in the button http://grab.by/Oov0

Comment: nevermind got it to work problem was that <button onclick="blah()"> wasnt working

Answer (score 1):

Declare `sendEmail` as global varibale by declaring it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sendEmail = function () {
        console.log("function send email run");
        var url = "sendemail.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
               {
                   //alert(data);
                   document.getElementById("resultmsg").innerHTML = data;//$("#resultmsg").html(data);
               }
        });

        return false;
    }
});
```

Or place `sendEmail` out of `document.ready` function:

```
function sendEmail() {
    console.log("function send email run");
    var url = "sendemail.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
           {
               //alert(data);
               document.getElementById("resultmsg").innerHTML = data;//$("#resultmsg").html(data);
            }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you Javascript file named `submit.js` and located in the `images` forder?
You don't need to declare `sendEmail` function in the `ready` function because it won't be available out of the scope of the anonymous function passed to the `ready` function. Only functions that are depending on a HTML elements are needed to be called in the `ready` function or to be included after the html code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write **sendEmail()** function outside **$(document).ready(function()**

With current code it is available only inside the **$(document).ready(function()** function

Comment: I have tried this, and still same error (and page just refreshes)